# how does this command execute: sed -n 'N ; s/#\n@/#--@/ ; P ; D' corruptData.txt

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I don't know why the sed command make the output as bellow:

shell command : `sed -n 'N ; s/#\n@/#--@/ ; P ; D' corruptData.txt`

output:

```
Header Line#--@#
@Data Line #1
Data Line #2#--@
End of Data Lines#--@
```

corruptData.txt:

```
Header Line#
@#
@Data Line #1
Data Line #2#
@
End of Data Lines#
@
```

I think the command was supposed to execute like:

```
step1: read 1first line 'Header Line#', and put it into pattern space.
step2: execute script command `N` : read line 2 '@#' into pattern space.
step3: execute script command `s/#\n@/#--@/`: now the content in pattern space is turned to be `Header Line#--@#`, and it is only one line of data.
step4: execute script command `P`: print the first line of data in the pattern space, namely `Header Line#--@#`
step5: execute script command `D`: delete the first line of data in the pattern space, so the pattern space is turned to be empty.
step6: execute script command `N`: read line 3 `@Data Line #1` into pattern space. Now it's the only data in the pattern space.
step7: execute script command `s/#\n@/#--@/ ; P ; D`: print `@Data Line #1`, delete it from pattern space and now pattern space is turned to be empty again.
step8: execute script command `N`: read line 4 `Data Line #2#` into pattern space, and now it's the only data in the pattern space.
step9: execute script command `s/#\n@/#--@/ ; P ; D`: print `Data Line #2#` and delete it, and now the pattern space.
....
stepN: execute script command `N`: read next line of data into pattern space.
stepN+1: execute script command `s/#\n@/#--@/ ; P ; D`: print the read line of data and delete it from pattern space.
....
```

thus, the output was supposed to be like :

```
Header Line#--@#
@Data Line #1
Data Line #2#
@
End of Data Lines#
@
```

Prints begins to be wrong from step 8 which is `Data Line #2#`, but the right print(3rd print) should be  `Data Line #2#--@`.

So, how does the command execute step by step and make the right output.

Thanks.

Comment: sorry. I used stepN, stepN+1 to say that the other steps will be like these two steps. And I have added some information to describe the question. Prints begins to be wrong from step 8 which is 'Data Line #2#', but the right print(3rd print) should be 'Data Line #2#--@'.

Comment: If I append another script command `p` to `N` : `sed -n 'N ; p ; s/#\n@/#--@/ ; p ; D' corruptData.txt`, the content of pattern space will be printed, once the script command `N` is executed. And from final the prints, I can see that after execute `D`,if the pattern space is empty, the sed command will continually executed from the next line, otherwise, the script command will continually execute.

Comment: This a task (trace my program) and not a question so it's off-topic.  You already established that your program is defective so how would it ever result in the "right output"?

Comment: Thanks, Allan. I just want to see what is pattern space after `N` is executed, so I put a `p` after the `N`. So the command `sed -n 'N ; p ; s/#\n@/#--@/ ; p ; D' corruptData.txt` just acts like a way to 'debug' for me.

Comment: You said that program generates (incorrect) output in the first code block and last code block shows the expected output.  So with "right output" you mean the first code block?  Why include the expected output then?  The correct program doesn't appear in the question.  I just suggest revise the question for clarity.   It sounds like you are a happy with Shawn's answer so make sure you accept it.

Comment: You could use the `--debug` option (GNU sed).

Comment: Did you try https://explainshell.com/?

Answer (score 2):

From the GNU sed manual's description of `D`:

> **If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as if the ‘d’ command was issued.** Otherwise, delete text in the pattern space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.

After the first two lines are read and merged and printed, there is no newline in the pattern space, so the `D` acts like `d`.

The next cycle reads `@Data Line #1`, the `N` adds a newline and `Data Line #2#` to the pattern space, leaving it as

```
@Data Line #1\nData Line #2#
```

The `s` doesn't match, the first line is printed and deleted from the pattern space, leaving it as just `Data Line #2#`. The cycle restarts without reading a new line, and then the `N` causes a newline and the next line after that, `@`, to be appended to the pattern space. So it's now

```
Data Line #2#\n@
```

which is turned into

```
Data Line #2#--@
```

by the `s`, and then printed and deleted - again, acting like `d` because there's no longer a newline. The next cycle then reads `End of Data Lines#`, and then the `N` and other commands are executed.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you to understand (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'N;s/#\n@/#--@/;P;D' corruptData.txt --debug
SED PROGRAM:
  N
  s/#\n@/#--@/
  P
  D
INPUT:   'corruptData.txt' line 1
PATTERN: Header Line#
COMMAND: N
PATTERN: Header Line#\n@#
COMMAND: s/#\n@/#--@/
MATCHED REGEX REGISTERS
  regex[0] = 11-14 '#
@'
PATTERN: Header Line#--@#
COMMAND: P
Header Line#--@#
COMMAND: D
INPUT:   'corruptData.txt' line 3
PATTERN: @Data Line #1
COMMAND: N
PATTERN: @Data Line #1\nData Line #2#
COMMAND: s/#\n@/#--@/
PATTERN: @Data Line #1\nData Line #2#
COMMAND: P
@Data Line #1
COMMAND: D
PATTERN: Data Line #2#
COMMAND: N
PATTERN: Data Line #2#\n@
COMMAND: s/#\n@/#--@/
MATCHED REGEX REGISTERS
  regex[0] = 12-15 '#
@'
PATTERN: Data Line #2#--@
COMMAND: P
Data Line #2#--@
COMMAND: D
INPUT:   'corruptData.txt' line 6
PATTERN: End of Data Lines#
COMMAND: N
PATTERN: End of Data Lines#\n@
COMMAND: s/#\n@/#--@/
MATCHED REGEX REGISTERS
  regex[0] = 17-20 '#
@'
PATTERN: End of Data Lines#--@
COMMAND: P
End of Data Lines#--@
COMMAND: D
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is overly complicated.  On the first line append the 2nd line to pattern buffer and patch up those two lines:

```
$ sed '1{N;s/\n/--/}' corruptData.txt
Header Line#--@#
@Data Line #1
Data Line #2#
@
End of Data Lines#
@
```

Comment: Thanks. May be it's complicated, but I really want to know how it executes. And the right output of my sed command is not that of your command, thanks again.